# How to get the source of request from Web Service?

Tags: java, soap, web-services, request, jax-ws

I want to get

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:prin="http://localhost/example">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
THIS
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

from webservice request I send from Java.

I use javax.jws

Answer (score 9):

This can be done programmatically (invasive) or by configuration without changing any code. [This page](https://jax-ws.dev.java.net/guide/Logging.html) documents how to configure JAX-WS RI:

To dump SOAP messages on the client side, use the following system property:

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

To dump SOAP messages on the server side, use the following system property:

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.HttpAdapter.dump=true
```

Answer (score 8):

Set the following VM property:

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.internal.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```

Comment: If you are using JAX-WS libraries baked into JDK 1.6 this will work. If you are using the JAX-RT jars with an earlier JDK you will need to use -Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true

The package names seemed to have changed when the library got baked into the JDK.

Comment: and you need to add jaxws-rt.jar to your project's classpath as well.